# Kotlin Execution order and result issues

Tags: firebase, kotlin, storage

I'm trying to get all files from firebase's storage through listAll.

By the way..

```
storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
                val image_task : FileDownloadTask
                for (fileRef in listResult.items) {
                    fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { Uri ->
                        image_list.add(Uri.toString())

                        println("size1 : " + image_list.size)
                    }
                }
                println("size2 : " + image_list.size)

            }//addOnSuccessListener
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRQCq.png)

Why is the execution order like this?

How do I solve it??

Comment: What exactly is wrong in that order? the `size2` that is printed before `size1`?

Comment: That's right, I think size 1 should be printed first and size 2 should be printed.
As you can see in the picture, size 2 is printed first as 0, and size 1 is printed later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a listener or callback to something, the code inside the listener will not be called until sometime later. Everything else in the current function will happen first.

You are adding listeners for each item using your for loop. No code in the listeners is running yet. Then your "size2" `println` call is made after the for loop. At some later time, all your listeners will fire.

If you want asynchronous code like this to be written sequentially, then you need to use coroutines. That's a huge topic, but your code would look something like this (but probably a little more involved than this if you want to properly handle errors). I'm using `lifecycleScope` from an Android Activity or Fragment for this example. If you're not on Android, you need to use some other CoroutineScope.

The calls to `await()` are an alternative to adding success and failure listeners. `await()` suspends the coroutine and then returns a result or throws an exception on failure.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val results = try {
            storageReference.listAll().await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Failed to get list: ${e.message}")
            return@launch
        }
    val uris = try {
            results.map { it.downloadUrl.await().toString() }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Failed to get at least one URI: ${e.message}")
            return@launch
        }
    image_list.addAll(uris)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the execution order here.

```
fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { Uri ->
```

the `downloadUrl` is an asynchronous action which means it doesn't wait for the action to actually complete in order to move along with the code.

You receive the result with the success listener (at least in this case)
If you want to deal with it in a sequential way, look at [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html).